# Artifact from CodeBuild cannot be deployed with CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

With CodeBuild I compile my SpringBoot application and put the resulting jar in a folder called `deploy/`. In my `buildspec.yml` at the end I provide:

```
artifacts:
   files:
    - deploy/*
```

When I plug this in to CodePipeline, this creates a zip file in S3. But the problem is, that this zip file contains the root folder, i.e. `deploy`. So the structure of the zip file is:

```
deploy.zip
  - deploy/
     - appspec.yml
     - app.jar
     - ...
```

This leads to the problem that CodeDeploy cannot find the `appspec.yml`, becuase it's not looking inside the deploy folder. I've been trying to overcome this providing a zip file as artifact at the end of the build process, but then in the pipeline it just gets zipped again..

Any idea how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new flag you can add in the artifacts section called `base-directory` to specify a base path for your artifacts package. This will allow you to truncate the `deploy/` path out of your artifacts without losing the rest of the structure underneath.

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - **/*
  base-directory: deploy
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html

Comment: This answer only worked if files values are string, eg: - 'deploy/*'

Answer (score 0):

You can add `discard-paths: yes`

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - deploy/*
  discard-paths: yes
```

Keep in mind that it discards ALL paths, including sub-directories

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html